# Why is my Nav bar sometimes sizing to the screens resolution on load/refresh/link click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The website in question can be found here:

http://elitepools.ca/index.php

It seems like the navigation works perfectly fine the majority of the time, but sometimes (especially if you refresh the page) the nav bar (div id magic-line-two) expands to consume the entire right side of the screen.

I've been working to fix this problem and the best I can come up with is that possibly some sort of set size  javascript might be able to size this properly but I'm still not entirely sure why this is happening so I was hoping with a bit of help I could isolate the problem and work on fixing it properly from there.

**Also this may or may not be unrelated, but once you go back to IE vers. 7 the page falls apart but I'm pretty sure that is a problem with my drop down as that's the part of the nav that cracks.

**Browsers this happens in:**

Firefox (semi-regularly)

Chrome (On page refresh but not link click)

Safari (On page refresh but not link click)

**Browsers this does NOT happen in**

IE 8+

Opera

Thank you to anybody who takes the time to help me out with this issue, please don't bother posting if you don't plan on taking a couple of minutes to look at the problem and offer legitimate assistance.

Comment: Are you talking about the navbar that focuses on whatever link you're currently hovering over? If so, it looks like it is set to have `right: 0px` (may not be what's happening, but it looks like it). I'm using Chrome, and it started filling up the whole right side and didn't change until I hovered over a link.

Comment: Yes that is what I am referring to, except if you click on a link it should function properly. The dark portion usually only stays on the page you are currently on. If you first visit the page or click a link and then f5 it the bar will expand all the way off the right side of the screen. (The bar size adjusts based on your resolution)

Comment: That's interesting. Can we see the CSS and JS of that portion of the page?

Comment: You sure can, just check page source and click on the included files. Primarily you're probably going to want to see these files: 

http://elitepools.ca/js/example.js
http://elitepools.ca/style.css

(In style check for /*Slidey Nav Stuff */ that's the code for the slidey nav stuff)

Comment: looks like whatever is resizing it, is also doing the width <li id="magic-line-two" style="width: 2489px; height: 104px; left: 48px;"></li> 2489px is a little excessive!

Comment: max-width:450px !important; set on #magic-line-two gives it a fairly normal structure

Comment: That sort of helps, it constricts it to not resizing beyond the entire screen. But the nav still breaks and consumes every link instead of just the one you are on. Thanks for that much though it does make it less noticeable.

Comment: ah gotcha, so it should never be wider than the current or highlighted link?

Comment: I also added a max-height: 70px; so that the drop down will always work even if the resize issue happens. Now the problem with the nav is coming up much more often. I'm not sure why this randomly happens and randomly does not happen. Click through the links a lot (like 10-20 times) in Firefox and you'll get a great idea of what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Xand94 exactly, the navigation is supposed to only highlight one item and it resizes itself based on the width of the nav item you have selected. When you mouse over other links it shifts the black area to that link and when you mouse off it animates back to that item.  (Bottom example) http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it is how you envisaged the design but

```
#magic-line-two {max-width:450px !important;}
```

works fine in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Same response I gave in the comments. That setting helps for when the error does occur but the navigation should function like the bottom example here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/

Comment: Hmm, looking at that, they set their magic-line-two to be the size of the element that it starts on whereas yours is huge (and they never set a max-width, just a width). Not sure if that's what you wanted, but if you set it to be the same width as the element that it starts on, you should get more of a similar thing going.

Comment: I gave that a shot, I set the width to 62px (The width of the index home page) and then loaded it up a few times. It broke and the bar ended up being the size of my screens resolution and shot way off the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your scripts are trying to manipulate elements before the CSS has loaded. Move the <link> tag above the script tags, and watch your problem disappear. :-)

```
...
<title>Elite Pool Builders</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://elitepools.ca/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
...
```

If you still see the problem after that, try removing these CSS imports...

```
@import "css/slider.css";
@import "css/pools.css";
@import "css/contact.css";
```

... and load them via <link> tags.